recursive data retrieval using snowflake
need one small help with recursive data retrieval using snowflake.
Assume we have a table with below structure



Job_id
Input database
Input table
Output database
Output table




1
permanent
source_1
temporary
intermediate_1


1
temporary
intermediate_1
temporary
intermediate_2


1
temporary
intermediate_2
permanent
target_1


3
permanent
source_1
permanent
target_3


2
permanent
source_2
temporary
intermediate_1


2
temporary
intermediate_1
permanent
target_2


4
permanent
target_1
permanent
target_4



I want to find data to start with

input database = permanent

and

input table = source_1

and find all the downstream for that source



Input database
Input table
Output database
Output table




permanent
source_1
permanent
target_1


temporary
intermediate_1
temporary
intermediate_2


temporary
intermediate_2
permanent
target_1


permanent
source_1
permanent
target_3


permanent
target_1
permanent
target_4



I am trying to use CONNECT BY to get data in above  way - but since the same table name is used in different job id - its picking records for job_id 2 as well.
How can i use recursion with a conditional field - like add job_id condition also when the prior database is temporary.

If I understand correctly , this is what you want to do :
SELECT *
FROM job_data
START WITH input_database = 'permanent' 
       AND input_table = 'source_1'
CONNECT BY input_database = PRIOR output_database 
       AND input_table = PRIOR output_table
       AND (  
            (PRIOR output_database = 'temporary' AND job_id = PRIOR job_id)
            OR PRIOR output_database = 'permanent'
           )

output :



JOB_ID
INPUT_DATABASE
INPUT_TABLE
OUTPUT_DATABASE
OUTPUT_TABLE




1
permanent
source_1
temporary
intermediate_1


3
permanent
source_1
permanent
target_3


1
temporary
intermediate_1
temporary
intermediate_2


1
temporary
intermediate_2
permanent
target_1


4
permanent
target_1
permanent
target_4




Hi. Thanks for the reply. I missed an additional scenario - just added it. If there is one more downstream with target_1 table going to target_4 - table . in that case we cannot add join with job_id.

@learn_more so in your question you mentioned you don't want job id2 becasue it's different from job id 1  and now the hierarchy leaks to a different job id. I'm not following the logic unfortunately.unless you meant the last line is still related to job id 1 , in that case the query still works

Last line is related to job_id -4.. so its more like source --> target_1 --> target_4. so we need both target_1 and Target_4 - since thats in path from source starting point

@learn_more see updated answer, I think I got what you want eventually
